# Midpoint algorithm for diameter with an even number of pixels?

Tags: geometry, bresenham

Using the [Midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) you can draw symmetrical circles, visiting each pixel only once. Due to the nature of the algorithm, it can only draw circles with an odd diameter (2 * r + 1). Is it possible to extend this algorithm so that it can successfully draw circles with a diameter with an *even* number of pixels?

Some requirements for the algorithm:

- Pixels must be drawn only once.
- RAM is very expensive.

If the Midpoint circle algorithm indeed cannot be modified to handle this, then the following solution would be fine:

```
void DrawCircle(int x, int y, int diameter)
{
    if (diameter % 2 == 0)
        EvenWidthCircle(x, y, diameter / 2);
    else
        MidpointCircle(x, y, diameter / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the midpoint algorithm for even diameters, but you have to do a little modification, for a diameter 8 circle, do a diameter 7 circle using the midpoint algorithm, then:

```
2 | 1
-----
3 | 4
```

For the octants in quadrant 1, do nothing. For 2, shift left 1. For 3, shift left and down. For 4, shift down,  then fill in the missing pixels/blocks/whatever you're making circles with.

Comment: This will not be as close to a circle as an odd numbered diameter, obviously, but it should be close for most applications.

Comment: Is this the common way of drawing a circle with an even diameter? E.g. Is this the algorithm behind GDI's `DrawEllipse`?

Comment: Honestly I don't know; it's just the solution that I worked out for drawing circles with turtles in minecraft's tekkit mod ^_^ I haven't found an algorithm specifically for even numbered circles. Looking at draw ellipse, it appears that it may using symmetry on an arc which is created relative to a bounding rectangle; however, that's just a guess.

Comment: As a small aside(I haven't tried yet ...) calculating an odd diameter one larger than the desired then removing points to transform it to a smaller circle may be a better fit than suggestion in topic. Really only important for very small diameters like 6/8/10, beyond that it will be fairly indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

A general idea is to split every pixel into 2x2 subpixels that doubles the diameter making it even.